# Unindo arrays onde os mesmos tiverem um certo campo igual

Tags: php, sql

Como faço para unir vários arrays em um array quando os mesmos tiverem os campos iguais?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho esse seguinte array sendo retornado, eu gostaria de agrupá-los em um único array onde eles tiverem o mesmo valor pro id_pergunta, por exemplo: nos 3 primeiros array que tem o id_pergunta = 1, os mesmos entrar em um array só, ficando, array = [ [array1], [array2], [array3] ]

P.S: Todos esses arrays estão dentro dentro de outro que está contido na variável $retorno

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o SQL é esse: `SELECT * FROM respostas INNER JOIN perguntas ON respostas.id_pergunta = perguntas.id_pergunta WHERE perguntas.id_questionario = $id_questionario`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se colocar, ***exemplo***:

```
while($result = $acesso->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{    
    $retorno[$result['id_pergunta']][] = $result;
}
```

vai agrupar pela chave `id_pergunta`, isso acontece porque a chave é a mesma para aquele determinado item do `array`, e o agrupamento acontece naturalmente.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)</sub>